# Time complexity of multiplication by repeated addition

Tags: time-complexity

Here is an example about analyzing the time complexity of different multiplication algorithm from my textbook:

If we do multiplication by repeated addition:

```
4 * 7 = 7 + 7 + 7 + 7
```

The time complexity would be O(n*10^n), where n is the digit.

I don't feel good about analyzing time complexity when n is digit. Could anyone explain to me why it is O(n*10^n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number *N* has *O*(log *N*) digits, where log denotes the decimal logarithm. The addition of *N* with itself therefore requires *O*(log *N*) steps, and doing that *M* times requires *O*(*M* log *N*) steps. For *M* in *O*(*N*) you get *O*(*N* log *N*) steps. This estimate is based on the numbers. If you want the number of digits *n* as base, you must substitute *N* with 10^*n*, which gives *O*(*n* 10^*n*).

Comment: Can you explain logic behind replacing it with 10^n